# “Object doesn't support property or method 'find'” in IE11 with Babel and Parcel

Tags: internet-explorer, babeljs, parcel

I keep getting this error in IE11 which stops all other js code to work. Seems babel is not compiling some code that uses the method 'find'. I've run out of things to google :)

Do i need a babel plugin?

My babel.config.json:

```
    {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "edge": "17",
            "firefox": "60",
            "chrome": "67",
            "safari": "11.1",
            "ie": "11"
          },
          "useBuiltIns": "usage",
          "corejs": "3.6.5"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "assets",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "parcel build ./assets/bundle.ts --public-url ./ -d ui",
    "watch": "parcel watch ./assets/bundle.ts --public-url ./ -d ui"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@types/throttle-debounce": "^2.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "normalize-scss": "^7.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.1.4",
    "postcss-modules": "^3.2.2",
    "sass": "^1.27.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@splidejs/splide": "^2.4.14",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "plyr": "^3.6.2",
    "throttle-debounce": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In which line and which file does the error throw?

I guess you're using `Array.prototype.find()` which is [not supported by IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility). You can also find the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) for this method on the page. I suggest you to include the polyfill in your code so that it can work with IE 11.

Besides, I find the below polyfill also work. You can also include it in your code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default,Array.prototype.includes,Array.prototype.find"></script>
```